# How to add club row values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, analytics

I have three table and I have do inner join in it,

```
select 
    s2.Sub_Name, po.ProductName, 
    s1.Quantity * po.Price as cost 
from
    (select Supplier, Product_ID, sum(Quantity) as Quantity 
     from sales 
     group by Supplier, Product_ID) s1
 inner join
     (select Sup_ID, Sub_Name from supplier) s2 on s1.Supplier = s2.Sup_ID
 inner join
     (select Product_ID, ProductName, Price from product) po on po.Product_ID = s1.Product_ID
```

This is the result that I get:

```
Sub_Name   ProductName  Cost
------------------------------
Supplier1  Prod10       88806
Supplier1  Prod3        21710
Supplier1  Prod8        79925
Supplier2  Prod8        16925
Supplier2  Prod4        52896
```

I want to club this Sub_name as

```
Sub_Name     Cost
----------------------
Supplier1    190441
Supplier2    69821
```

Please help me get to this output.

Comment: do you need product name in final result set ?

Comment: Have you tried a `GROUP BY` ?

Answer (score 1):

Just

```
select 
    s2.Sub_Name, sum  ( s1.Quantity * po.Price) as cost 
from
    (select Supplier, Product_ID, sum(Quantity) as Quantity 
     from sales 
     group by Supplier, Product_ID) s1
 inner join
     (select Sup_ID, Sub_Name from supplier) s2 on s1.Supplier = s2.Sup_ID
 inner join
     (select Product_ID, ProductName, Price from product) po on po.Product_ID = s1.Product_ID 
Group by s2.Sub_Name
```